# array summation and merging based on uniqueness of element at certain position + ruby arrays

Tags: ruby, arrays

I have a 2D array as below

```
[[1, 4.0, "burger"], [1, 8.0, "tofu_log"], [2, 5.0, "burger"], [2, 6.5, "tofu_log"]]
```

Here, each element is a collection of restaurant_id, price and item. The task is to return unique restaurant_id, sum of prices, and the items such that the sum should be minimum. I want to get

```
[[1, 12.0, "burger, tofu_log"], [2, 11.5, "burger, tofu_log"]]
```

I have done it as below

```
arr
  => [[1, 4.0, "burger"], [1, 8.0, "tofu_log"], [2, 5.0, "burger"], [2, 6.5, "tofu_log"]] 
ids = arr.map{|i| i[0]}.uniq
  => [1, 2] 
a = ids.map{|id| arr.map{|i| i if i[0] == id }.compact}
  => [[[1, 4.0, "burger"], [1, 8.0, "tofu_log"]], [[2, 5.0, "burger"], [2, 6.5, "tofu_log"]]] 
a.map{|x| [x[0][0], x.map{|y| y[1]}.inject(:+), x.map{|i| i[2..-1]}.join(', ')] }.sort{|x| x[1]}.first
=> [2, 11.5, "burger, tofu_log"]
```

Is there any less complicated way?

Comment: what do you mean by *the items such that the sum should be minimum* ?

Comment: @ArupRakshit in the above case the sum of items is 12.0 and 11.5. i wanted to show the restaurant where the sum of prices of items would be minimum.

Comment: @ArupRakshit sorting can be done on a specific index. i wanted a elegant solution which should be readable as my solution was working but was too messy.

Comment: RE *sum should be minimum*.  I'm confused.  You sort on the sum of prices lowest to highest but show a desired result that is highest to lowest.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
arr.group_by { |rest_id, _| rest_id }.map do |rest_id, items| 
  [rest_id, 
   items.map { |_, price| price }.inject(:+), 
   items.sort.map { |_, _, product| product }.join(", ") ]
end
# => [[1, 12.0, "burger, tofu_log"], [2, 11.5, "burger, tofu_log"]]
```

Comment: Your one is correct.. As I didn't notice the sorting fact.. +1

Comment: Nice use of `group_by`, Uri.  Consider doing some disambiguation for better readability.  For example: `arr.group_by { |id,_| id }`, 
`items.inject(0) { |tot, (_,price)| tot+price }`, `items.sort.map { |_,_,product| product }`.  The second suggestion also simplifies a bit.

Comment: Humm proper naming helps to read code better way... Good suggestions @CarySwoveland

Answer (score 1):

Here's one way to do that.

**Code**

```
def doit(arr)
  arr.each_with_object({}) { |(id,price,item),h| h.update({id=>[price,[item]]}) \
       {|_,(o_price,o_item), (n_price,n_item)|[o_price+n_price, o_item+n_item]}}
     .map { |id, (tot_price,*items)| [id, tot_price, items].flatten }
     .sort_by { |_,tot_price| tot_price }
end
```

This sorts on the total price, lowest to highest.  If you want to sort highest to lowest, as in your example, replace the sort criterion `tot_price` with `-tot_price`, or tack `.reverse` to the very end.

**Example**

```
arr = [[1, 4.0, "burger"], [1, 8.0, "tofu_log"],
       [2, 5.0, "burger"], [2, 6.5, "tofu_log"]]

doit(arr)
  #=> [[2, 11.5, "burger", "tofu_log"], [1, 12.0, "burger", "tofu_log"]]
```

**Explanation**

Let's look at this line-by-line, using the example above,

```
arr.each_with_object({}) { |(id,price,item),h|...}
```

Here [Enumerable#each_with_object](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.1/Enumerable.html#method-i-each_with_object) creates an empty hash (the "object) and passes each element of `arr` to the block.  The first is `[1, 4.0, "burger"]`, which assigns the following values to the block variables:

```
id    #=> 1
price #=> 4.0
item  #=> "burger"
h     #=> {}
```

If we did not have the parentheses around `id,price,item` Ruby would raise an exception because it would be expecting just two parameters: the element (array) of `arr` and the hash created by `each_with_object`.  The parentheses tell Ruby that we are *disambiguating* the element of `arr` into its three constituent components.

We now use [Hash#update](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.1/Hash.html#method-i-update) (aka `merge!`) to merge a hash formed from this first element  of `arr`into the hash `h`, which is presently empty.  The hash we are merging is

```
{id=>[price,[item]]} #=> {1=>[4.0,["burger"]]}
```

Since `h` does not have a key `1`, this hash is merged, so now

```
h #=> {1=>[4.0,["burger"]]}
```

The next element of `arr` is `[1, 8.0, "tofu_log"]` so the block variables are assigned the values

```
id    #=> 1
price #=> 8.0
item  #=> "tofu_log" (yuk!)
h     #=> {1=>[4.0,["burger"]]}
```

We now attempt to merge the hash

```
{id=>[price,[item]]} #=> {1=>[8.0,["tofu_log"]]}
```

but since the hash `h` already has the key `1`, `update`'s block

```
{|k,(o_price,o_item), (n_price,n_item)| [o_price + n_price, o_item + n_item]}
```

is used to determine the merged value for the key `1` (the raison d'être for the block).

This block has these values:

```
{|1,(4.0,["burger"]), (8.0,["tofu_log"])| [4.0 + 8.0, ["burger"]+["tofu_log"|}
```

The first block variable is the key, which equals `1`, but since we are not using it, I have replaced it with an underscore (placeholder), to emphasize it is not being used.  The second block variable ("old value") is the value for `1` in the merged hash and the third value ("new value") is the value for `1` in the hash we are merging.

The merged value for key `1` therefore becomes

```
[12.0, ["burger, "tofu_log"]]
```

so the hash is now

```
h => { 1=>[12.0, ["burger, "tofu_log"]] }
```

After passing the remaining two elements of `arr` to the block, `each_with_object` returns the hash

```
h => {1=>[12.0, ["burger", "tofu_log"]], 2=>[11.5, ["burger", "tofu_log"]]}
```

We then use [Enumerable#map](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.1/Enumerable.html#method-i-map) to convert the hash to an array with the desired format.

For the first element of `h` the block variables are

```
id    => 1
items => [12.0, ["burger, "tofu_log"]]
```

We apply [Array#flatten](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.1/Array.html#method-i-flatten):

```
[id, tot_price, items].flatten
  #=> [1, 12.0, ["burger, "tofu_log"]].flatten
  #=> [1, 12.0, "burger, "tofu_log"]
```

The final operation is to sort, but I am not certain what is to be sorted, so I won't  discuss that.

Comment: @Cary i am sure that the above solution works but i cant find the method 'each_with_object' in http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.1/Array.html. Would you please add some explanation about the approach.

Comment: prasad, it is [Enumerable#each_with_object](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.1/Enumerable.html#method-i-each_with_object) (version 1.9+).  It is a very useful method, a good replacement for [Enumerable#reduce](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.1/Enumerable.html#method-i-reduce) (aka `inject`) in many situations.